# Material UI react select all children except for last child not working?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I can select all children:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  icons: {
    "&>*": {
      backgroundColor: "red",
    },
  },
}))
```

JSX:

```
    <Grid item>
      <Grid container direction="column" classes={{ root: classes.icons }}>
        <Grid item>
          <img src={facebook} alt="facebook" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <img src={twitter} alt="twitter" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <img src={instagram} alt="instagram" />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

But selecting all but last child is not working:

```
 icons: {
    "&:not(:last-child)": {
      backgroundColor: "red",
    },
  },
```

What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `sx` and was able to achieve what you are looking for.

```
const gridSx = {
  "& >*": {
    backgroundColor: "green"
  },
  "& :not(:last-of-type)": {
    backgroundColor: "red"
  }
};
...
<Grid container direction="column" sx={gridSx}>...
```

Here is a the sandbox: [sanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basicgrid-demo-material-ui-forked-3lp833?file=/demo.tsx)

Comment: Omg so it was just the spacing? Thanks for your help!

Comment: A space after the '&' means to select children of the element, if you omit the space it means you are selecting the element itself. I will try to find again a list explaining the selectors from the MUI documentation and post it.

Comment: Found a guide here explaining in more detail: https://www.querythreads.com/css-child-selector-in-mui/